# How to show fixed element in center bottom

Tags: css

I want to show `<div class="fe"></div>` in perfect center. When I use `left: 50%;` its works but not showing in perfect center.

```
.fe {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: `left: calc(50% - 75px);` or `margin-left: -75px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Add `transform: translateX(-50%)`.

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
.fe {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fe"></div>
```

**Method 2:**

Use negative margin equal to half of element width. i.e as you have `width` of `.fe` `150px` so use `margin-left: -75px`

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
.fe {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: -75px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fe"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the element to move 50% left its own size:

```
transform:translateX(-50%);
```

Like this:

```
.fe {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of setting left to 50%, set left=0 and right=0 and margin=auto.. this will center automatically to center.

```
.fe {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
width: 150px;
height: 50px;
background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `margin-left` and `margin-right` as shown below

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Setting both these to `auto` will center the division. For further info in this regard, you can refer [this tutorial](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use  property align="center" for div

```
 .fe{ align="center"
    }
```

Or in div you can define

```
<div class="fe" align="center"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Add `transform: translateX(-50%);` property to your code

```
.fe {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
left: 50%;
width: 150px;
height: 50px;
background-color: black;
transform: translateX(-50%);
margin:auto;
}
```